# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined :ionic.bundle.min.js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am receiving Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error on the recharge of a certain page of my ionic app.

I want to send the id of the advert selected in the details page to list all the details of this item

The error comes up after the page was reloaded.
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sccy0.jpg)

service.js

```js
.factory('Annonces', function($http, $q) {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON arra
    var dfd = $q.defer();
    var allannonces ;
      $http.get("http://localhost/json.php").then(function(response){
        annonces = response.data;
        console.log(annonces);
        dfd.resolve(annonces);   
        allannonces = annonces;
        console.log(allannonces);
        });
  return {
    all: function(){
       return dfd.promise;
      },
     get: function(annonceId) {
          for (var i = 0; i < allannonces.length; i++) {
        if (allannonces[i].id === parseInt(annonceId)) {
          return allannonces[i];
          console.log(allannonces[i]);
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
  
});
```

controller.js

```js
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])


.controller('AnnoncesCtrl', function($scope, allannonces) {
  
   $scope.annonces = allannonces;

})

.controller('AnnonceDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Annonces) {
  $scope.annonce = Annonces.get($stateParams.annonceId);
  console.log($scope.annonce);
})
```

app.js

```js
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider


.state('annonces', {
      url: '/annonces',
  
          templateUrl: 'templates/annonces.html',
          controller: 'AnnoncesCtrl',
          resolve: {
        allannonces: function(Annonces) {
          return Annonces.all(); }
      }
        }
    )

.state('details', {
      url: '/annonces/:annonceId',
          templateUrl: 'templates/details.html',
          controller: 'AnnonceDetailCtrl'

        }
      
    )
  
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/annonces');

});
```

Comment: Are you reading it before the Ajax call is returned?

Comment: I do not understand your question ?